# Laurent series for $\cosh(z)$

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

In particular, since $\cosh(z) = \frac{e^{z}+e^{-z}}{2}$, and $e^{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!}$, why is it not the case that $\cosh(z) = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!} + (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!})^{-1}}{2} = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!} + (\sum_{n=0}^{-\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!})}{2} = \frac{\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!}+1}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-z)^n}{n!} \neq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{0} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$ Also, $n!$ is not defined for $n <0$.

Comment: Yes, the fact about $n!$ undefined for $n<0$ makes it quite obvious. However, could you perhaps elaborate on why $e^{-z} \neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{z^{n}}$ but rather the above? (Or why they are equivalent)

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{a+b} \neq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}.$$

Comment: But is it not true that $(z + z^2 + z^3 + ...)^{-1} = (1/z + 1/z^2 + ...)$? So $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {z^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {1/z^n} \neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-z)^{n}}$ ?

Comment: No, it's not true.

Comment: Haha, it seems so clear now, of course it's not true. Thanks. Seems I need a break for the books.